# "How To Format" guide has misleading UI elements

Tags: discussion, feature-request, formatting, help-center

The "How To Format" guide on the right side of the screen is misleading.  It uses "►" for each item in the list.

[image]

Usually this "►" means that the list item is expandable, but it is not an expandable list. 
 
I believe that a round or square bullet would be better suited to this list.

Does anyone else believe that this styling is misleading?

Comment: While the question is interesting, it may be outside of the scope of simply Code Review Meta: the same "problem" exists in all the sites of the network. I would consider asking it on [Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/) instead in order to have more feedback :)

Comment: The SE devs routinely patrol all meta sites, and there is no specific guidance/requirement to post to meta.stackexchange. Also, in this case, I should point out that some mods have specifically drawn the SE Dev attention to this post. It is fine where it is. (CC. FYI @Morwenn )

Comment: @rolfl Ok, I didn't know. That's good to hear :)

Comment: This is a popular feature request at [meta.SE]: [Can we get rid of the disclosure triangles that don't disclose anything on the edit screen?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/195779/224428)